# AngularJS - $http Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-mvc, angular-ui-router

I have created Single Page Application using Angularjs. I am facing follwing problem when navigating pages.

**Problem 1:**

Below `$http` call hits Spring Controller, gets processed successfully and this spring method return bean.

`@RequestMapping(value="/getStatus",method=RequestMethod.GET)`

After I get response from server side, it's going to the error block in JS method

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) -> /getStatus

Why its going to error block after successfully processed?

**Problem 2:**

Even though I'm navigating page from error block using `state.go`, `Acknowledgement.jsp` is rendered and `{{status}}` --> printing as empty

I am struggling with AngularJs & UI router for 2 days. Kindly help

### Progress.jsp

```
<div ng-controller="myctrl as mydata" ng-init="getStatus()">
    // progress icon here
</div>
```

### MyCtrl.js

```
$scope.getStatus = function() {

$http({
    url: CONTEXT_PATH + 'getStatus',
    method: "GET",
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("success block : "+status);
        $scope.paymentStatus = data.epaymentStatus;
        $state.go("Acknowledgement");
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("failure block : "+status);
        $scope.paymentStatus = data.epaymentStatus;
        $state.go("Acknowledgement");
    });

};
```

### Acknowledgement.jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log("Status :: "+status);
// Here status printing as SUCCESS
</script>

<div ng-controller="myctrl as mydata" id="RESPONSE">
{{status}} --> printing empty
<div class="row row-space" ng-if="status == 'SUCCESS'">
</div>
</div>
```

### ProcessController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getStatus",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ProcessBean getStatus(HttpServletRequest 
httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
    ProcessBean processBean = new ProcessBean();
    try {
        // Business process takes place here
        processBean.setStatus("SUCCESS");
        httpRequest.setAttribute("processStatus", "S");

    } catch(Exception e) {
        processBean.setStatus("FAILURE");
        httpRequest.setAttribute("processStatus", "S");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return processBean;
}
```

Comment: Please show your code on the server side where your $http send the request to.

Comment: @holydragon.. Thanks for your reply. I have updated my code. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Solved my first problem by adding @ResponseBody in the method.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getStatus",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ProcessBean getStatus(HttpServletRequest 
httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
    ProcessBean processBean = new ProcessBean();
    try {
        // Business process takes place here
        processBean.setStatus("SUCCESS");
        httpRequest.setAttribute("processStatus", "S");

    } catch(Exception e) {
        processBean.setStatus("FAILURE");
        httpRequest.setAttribute("processStatus", "S");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return processBean;
}
```